# MediaElement Support in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mediaelement, h.264

I am evaluating WPF and Silverlight for a Project. I find WPF to be most suited for our purpose since we require performance, graphics support, Office compatibility and the ability to support ActiveX controls. It is also a Desktop application. However there is one area where i find Silverlight to be superior - Media support. I would like to have the WPF mediaelement control to support MPEG4 (H.264) codec.
Can anyone please suggest if this is feasible somehow and if support for the same is in the roadmap of WPF?

Comment: I did try with D3DImage. While i could make some headway with the help of examples, i couldn't really figure out how to play Video elements using it let alone using it as a replacement of MediaElement. Any pointers to this?

Answer (score 1):

The WPF MediaElement uses DirectShow under the convers (well it uses WMP, but WMP uses DShow), so as long as you have an h264 codec installed (Windows 7 comes with them), your MediaElement should be able to play h264 video.

Answer (score 1):

The WPF MediaElement requires the Windows Media Player 10 or above (this can be some deployment problem, so please read the [Redistributing Windows Media Player Software](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb262811%28VS.85%29.aspx)) and uses DirectShow filter (codecs) installed on the user's computer. A general rule is if you can play your file in WMP you can play it in MediaElement.

For Silverlight you can found here the [Supported Media Formats, Protocols, and Log Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with WPF media element but it has some performance hit. so if u have to show image and video you can use D3DImage of WPF in SP1 of .NET 3.5 that is new control of WPF for DirectX interaction and it has better performance over media element. more on [D3DImage](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/D3DImage.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The following msdn pages seem to have a more elaborate walkthrough for using D3DImage.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656785.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656716.aspx

Let me try and revert back.
Thanks

Comment: I did try with D3DImage. While i could make some headway with the help of examples, i couldn't really figure out how to play Video elements using it let alone using it as a replacement of MediaElement. Any pointers to this?

Comment: http://www.codeplex.com/WPFMediaKit here is the example of playing video, DVD, Webcam and lot more using D3DImage.